# Adobe Flash Professional CS6 for Android: Navigate from One movie-clip to another move-clip using Actionscript 3 class

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I have created one 'login page' which is a movieclip. and my another page is 'home' which is another movie clip. so what i want to do is.. `i wanna navigate my one move-clip to another movie clip`. and `` `i don'n want to use timeline ``. `just by codding` in actionscript class.
  i was searching same from 3 hours on Google but i din't get any useful snippet.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The 'login page' movie clip must be added to some parent. Do a removeChild of the 'login page' and do an addChild of the second movie clip 'home'